# What would be the intensity of light if polarizer is additionally absorbing some percent of light?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, optics

I came across one question that said the polarizers are additionally absorbing 10% of light. So, can I write (I/2)(9/10) or (I)(4/10) as final intensity of light where I is initial intensity. Reasoning for first case is that 90% of I/2 is emitted whereas second case tells that instead of 50% of intensity it is now emitting 40%. I am confused between them also, I don't know what will I do for second and third polarisers.

[image]

Comment: Please do *not* post images of text. You need to type any relevant text into your question. And please see [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) for the site's policy on homework-like questions.

Comment: BTW, I/2 is wrong. What is $\cos(30°)$?

Comment: @PM 2Ring I am confused with the concept that has to be used in this question and I have written all of that thing. The image is to give idea about what question I am talking about. To me both the cases look logical but only one has to be correct. My focus is on what reasoning is correct in this question. Also, the angle of first polarizer does not matter(idk if I am wrong, I was taught this only). The intensity of light emitted after passing through first polarizer is always I/2. Please help me if I am wrong

Comment: Ok, but what I said about posting proper text instead of an image still applies. You really should try to make it clearer in your question *exactly* what concepts you are having trouble with. But I think I understand what those conceptual problems are, so I will write you an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you said:

> The intensity of light emitted after passing through first polarizer is always I/2.

That's correct if the incoming light is unpolarised, but in this exercise we are told that the incoming light has vertical polarisation. So to get the intensity after the 1st polariser we need to use the cosine formula.
But we are also told that each polariser additionally absorbs 10% of the light. So the full formula we need for the 1st polariser is
$$I = 0.9 I_0\cos^2(30°)$$

Now when that light hits the 2nd polariser, the angle between the light's polarisation axis and the polariser is once again 30°, so we can use the same formula again. And the same logic applies to the 3rd polariser. So our final formula is
$$I = 0.9^3 I_0\cos^6(30°)$$

In other words, we can simply multiply all of the reduction factors together. That's physically valid because the effects of the filters are linear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have a doubt, let's suppose the light was unpolarised then can we write intensity of light coming out from first polarizer as 0.4 I because in general case it is 0.5 I so after 10% absorption it should be 0.4 I or should it be (0.5 I) (90/100) meaning 90% (after 10% absorption )of intensity of what was supposed to be emitted. Please help.

Comment: @Piyush If the light source is unpolarised, then after the 1st polariser the intensity is $0.45I_0$. To do the 10% reduction have to *multiply* $0.5\times 0.90$